# disadvantages of Parcels in cloudera

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have to differentiate between Cloudera parcel process and writing a cook book or a reciepe of a Chef for installation of packages in a cluster.

So i'm looking for advantages and disadvantage between Parcel over Chef or Vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Cloudera Manager, parcels allow you to install/update CDH on your cluster(s) in its entirety via a single package (or, install add-on components such as betas and Cloudera Labs releases). From the docs:

- Parcels are self-contained and installed in a versioned directory,
  which means that multiple versions of a given parcel can be installed
  side-by-side. You can then designate one of these installed versions
  as the active one. With packages, only one package can be installed
  at a time so there's no distinction between what's installed and
  what's active.
- Parcel handling automatically downloads, distributes, and activates
  the correct parcel for the operating system running on each host in
  the cluster.

Parcels can only be installed via CM, so if you're not a CM user, your question is an academic one. If you are a CM user, you can choose to use either parcels (which is certainly easier) or a packages-based approach via Chef or Puppet (not as easy, but some people prefer it nonetheless).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Parcels: What and Why? · cloudera/cm_ext Wiki](https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/Parcels:-What-and-Why%3F), there are a number of benefits using parcels, including:

- having a consistent image of the cluster (all components adhere to the same version)
- managing rolling upgrades with ease (thanks to having two versions coexist on the same host)
- using non privileged folders for the binaries.

It is sometimes observed that one of the most challenging parts of administering a Hadoop cluster are upgrades, so probably parcels will help the most in that sense.

With that respect, note that **Cloudera Manager** will be able to install the components initially with packages, but it will **manage upgrades only if you had chosen the parcels option**.